# How to make bootstrap datepicker collapse, once the date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker in my angular app in the following way:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="textinput">Requested Complition Date</label>
   <div class="input-append date" id="datepickerRequestedCompletionDate" data-date="05-15-2014" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
       <input size="16" type="text" value="05-15-2014" readonly ng-model="RequestedCompletionDate">
       <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Currently ,When the date is picked, the dropdown remains extended.
What can I do to make the dropdown collapse once the date is selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#datepickerRequestedCompletionDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
   $('#datepickerRequestedCompletionDate').datepicker('hide')
  });
```